# Find Days between dates gives me a fraction

Tags: sharepoint-designer, date-time

I'm using a 2013 workflow that starts on creation, and the Find days between dates code. I'm getting the time from the "Due Date" field on the list, it comes with a time, so I set time for 12:00:00 in the first step. Here is the whole workflow
[image]

And this is what I get in the log: the date, 1/4/2016 12:00:00 AM, then the date variable and the time variable which is the days in between.

[image]

I should be getting 116 in time variable obviously. I've tried setting the date, 1/4/2016, to a date variable first then use the variable in the code but I still get the same results.

Comment: So there are 385,920 minutes between 1/4/2016 12:00:00 and 9/28/2016 12:00:00 but if I run a workflow on SharePoint to make this calculation it calculates there are 385,860 minutes, 60 minutes less! That's why I was getting a weird number between dates.

Comment: Is this a leap year issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out! The 60 minute loss is from daylight savings time. So I have to put in my code, if the date being checked is during daylight savings time, add 60 minutes.

Comment: okay, Great you figured out. just curious, is there anything in SPD workflow which will indicate that daylight saving is started?

Comment: Gaurravs - actually that was going to be my next question / comment! I think I'll need a new question posted!? I was just looking at REST API functionality (I've never used in SP before) in SP for another project. I'm wondering if I can use that on a site that tells me yes or no that we are in Daylight savings time and if so add the 60 minute difference?

Comment: I figure out a much simple solution to my issue - I check the long date, which will display like, "Saturday, November 19, 2016". Then I check to see if the due date contains Saturday or Sunday, and if so, add the appropriate number of days so the due day doesn't fall on the weekend.